# bazel build tensorflow application outside Tensorflow source tree

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I want to deploy my TF models in a binary executable. following [This post](https://medium.com/@hamedmp/exporting-trained-tensorflow-models-to-c-the-right-way-cf24b609d183#.cvrg2neaz), it seems I can use bazel to build my application within TF's source tree, just like [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc).

My question is, do I have to always write my application code in TF source directory? I know CMake support out source build, which means I can define the external dependency (i.e. TF) for my application, and use bazel to build my application.

More generally, I'm looking for an example of build application with external dependency (e.g. TF). There seems not many example code for bazel right now.

Comment: I just found https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6706 and am studying it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to write your application code in TF source directory, see the [tensorflow_serving example](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic)

short explanantion is: after training,

1.convert your model into [`saved_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model) format which contains the graph definition and trained weights

2.build tensorflow_model_server with bazel which can deploy your model to a server

3.write a client script that can send request to server and get a response

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I know the TF serving project, but haven't seen a minimal example of building an app out of TF. Can you elaborate a bit on step 2, i.e. how to write build rules to notify Bazel that my app has external dependency TF?

Comment: what do you mean by extenrnal dependency? another python package? I can't think of a situation where you need external dependency in step 2 because it just builds the binary file tensorflow_model_server from tf-serving source and this file accepts your saved_model path as a parameter so as to serve it, nothing else. Do you mean some packages doing preprocessing in step 3?

Comment: I want to build TF as an library (e.g. .so or .a) and develop my application outside TF source tree, and use TF as external dependency.